# How do you set the SDK for IntelliJ IDEA's Ruby plugin?

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea

Using IntelliJ Idea 15.0.6 with the Ruby plugin v.8.0.0.20160205

After encountering various Ruby SDK problems, I followed these instructions to re-configure my inherited Ruby project: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/configuring-global-project-and-module-sdks.html

I now have a global SDK:
[image]

And a project SDK:
[image]

And a module SDK (inherited from the project SDK)
[image]

But gemfiles showed a bunch of inspection problems
[image]

And I was not able to create a Run/Debug Configuration using the module SDK.  Specifically, if I selected the "Choose SDK from module" radio button for Ruby SDK when creating a new Run/Debug Configuration, I would see the error "No SDK specified" at the bottom of the window.

What is going on?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Turns out that the module was not a Ruby module.  This is what it should look like:

[image]

I deleted the module and recreated it and everything is working correctly.  Many times I've found that the process of writing out a question is a great way to answer it myself.

Comment: It's another bug in intellij. I had to delete the module and recreate it too, even though it was the same exact thing. I also had to specify the location as the existing location of my app, and it will ask you if you want to overwrite the existing location, of course I don't. I had problems with intellij when working with android too. That was an even bigger nightmare.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this a million times! Thanks @ed-norris!

Comment: I am back here again. Completely forgot about this stupid bug.

Comment: FINALLY! Thank you